# how to contruct struts-config.xml file

Tags: struts

I am Getting

""parsing error processing resource path /web-inf/struts-config.xml""

Exception when i am Deploying Struts Application in Apache 6 Server

Please help to solve this problem

Comment: How can we help solve the problem? We can't see your config file--but whatever it is, it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your struts-config.xml is having some parsing problem i.e. some xml tags are not proper.
Try to open it in IE if you are able to see the contents there or try to find out what's missing in it.

Comment: Opening it in Notepad ++ can also help in finding the missing tags issues.